# how to compare two lists using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file

I have two lists how can I check if  list1 has some items that are from list2

for ie i have:

```
list1 = ["car","424", "fwe"]
list2 = ["car", "cat"]
```

maybe something like  this:

```
if list1 has elements from  list2
```

then return true

Answer (score 8):

You can use LINQ `Intersect`, `Except` functions.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Intersect with Any:

```
list1.Intersect(list2).Any()
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution really depends on the specifics of your situation.

For instance, you could compare each pair of elements, which would be a very straightforward implementation. However, this isn't particularly efficient if the lists are long.

A second option would be to add all the elements of one list to a HashSet, and then try to add all the elements of the second list. If there is an element in common, the HashSet Add() method will return false when you try to add the duplicate. This will be faster for large lists, but requires additional memory, and may produce less readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
list1.Any(e => list2.Contains(e));
```